# Select object from a listbox and show correponding objects in another listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a Form1 where I create Medic objects and add them to listaMedici1. In Form2 I create Pacient objects, added them to listapacienti2 and them send that list to Form1.

In Form1 I have 2 listboxes: In listbox1_medici i show the list of Medic objects. 
What I want to do is that when I select a Medic object from listbox1_medici, in listbox2_pacienti to show all the Pacient objects, that have the field codM, the same as the the selected object field codM. I have tried this method, but it doesn't work. What could be wrong? Thank you.

Form1: 
Button3 is used to populate listbox1_medici with Medic objects

And the method SelectieItem and event SelectedIndexChanged were supposed to show the Pacient objects that have the same codM as the Medic object selected in listbox1_medici..but they don't work

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<Medic> listaMedici1 = new List<Medic>();
        public List<Pacient> listaPacienti1 = new List<Pacient>();
        public ArrayList specialitati = new ArrayList();

        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        specialitati.Add("Endocrinologie");
        specialitati.Add("Oftalmologie");
        specialitati.Add("Neurologie");
        specialitati.Add("Cardiologie");
        for (int i = 0; i < specialitati.Count; i++)
            comboBox1spec.Items.Add(specialitati[i]);

        Medic m1 = new Medic(1, "Ionescu", "Endocrinologie");
        Medic m2 = new Medic(2, "Popescu", "Cardiologie");
        listaMedici1.Add(m1);
        listaMedici1.Add(m2);



    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//this is where i create objects using the textboxes
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2(listaMedici1);
      //  form.listaMedici2 = listaMedici1;
        form.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Medic m in listaMedici1)
        {
            if(!(listBox1_medici.Items.Contains(m)))
            {
                listBox1_medici.Items.Add(m.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void SelectieItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(listBox1_medici.SelectedItems.Count==1)
        {
            Medic med = listBox1_medici.SelectedItem as Medic;
            for(int i=0;i<listaPacienti1.Count;i++)
            {
                if(med.CodM==listaPacienti1[i].CodM)
                {
                    listBox2_pacienti.Items.Add(listaPacienti1[i].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void listBox2_pacienti_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectieItem(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public List<Medic> listaMedici2 = new List<Medic>();
    public List<Pacient> listaPacienti2 = new List<Pacient>();
    Form1 form1;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Pacient p1 = new Pacient(1, "Danut", 2, 230);
        Pacient p2 = new Pacient(2, "Cristi", 1, 120);
        listaPacienti2.Add(p1);
        listaPacienti2.Add(p2);
    }

    public Form2(List<Medic> listaMedici1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listaMedici2 = listaMedici1;
        foreach (Medic med in listaMedici2)
        {
            comboBox1codmed.Items.Add(med.CodM.ToString());
        }
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//this is where i create Pacient objects using the textboxes
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.listaPacienti1 = listaPacienti2;
        frm.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is allot of code, can you narrow the issue down to a subset of the code please?

Comment: @Kami, done, I added comments to some methods, and only let the main ones that might be useful to solving my issue

Comment: Use data-binding.

Comment: First - you say that you are using `listbox` but in code i can see `combobox` so what are you using. Second - could you show your `Medic` and `Pacient` classes?